# Switch windows with alt + left and alt + right

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, 18.10

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10, and I want to switch between the windows using the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd>, like on macOS.
Is this possible?

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> didn't worked to me because it only switch between the last opened windows.